# Offering a bounty on someone else's question - 100 points minimum?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I'd like to offer a bounty on someone else's question, though the minimum I can offer is 100 points of reputation.

Posting this question in itself demonstrates my lack of generosity of spirit, yet at the same time I'm curious to know why I must offer up 100 points instead of the 50 points minimum which I could offer on my own question!

Comment: If that question already has an answer that is posted by you before, then the minimum points you must offer is 100. Check [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).  But if that is not the case in your scenario,  then i guess it must be SO policy

Comment: Thanks Gautam, that does explain it.  I did Answer the question already.  I could delete my Answer and then put it up for a 'cheaper' bounty, but I think the Answer is worth keeping as part of the research.  I read about the [reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64824/clever-bounty-reputation-hack/64826#64826) for the '100 points policy if you've posted an Answer on the question', but I think for SP SE it makes less sense.  I seldom see questions receiving 10 upvotes!  Although searching I do find several hundred, but these are spread over several years...